# sapply() with strsplit in R

Tags: r, strsplit

I found this code:

```
string = c("G1:E001", "G2:E002", "G3:E003")
> sapply(strsplit(string, ":"), "[", 2)
[1] "E001" "E002" "E003"
```

clearly `strsplit(string, ":")` returns a vectors of size 3 where each component i is a vector of size 2 containing `Gi` and `E00i`.

But why the two more arguments `"[", 2` have the effect to select only those `E00i`? As far as I see the only arguments accepted by the function are:

```
sapply(X, FUN, ..., simplify = TRUE, USE.NAMES = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the docs for `?sapply`:

```
 sapply(X, FUN, ..., simplify = TRUE, USE.NAMES = TRUE)

 FUN: the function to be applied to each element of ‘X’: see
      ‘Details’.  In the case of functions like ‘+’, ‘%*%’, the
      function name must be backquoted or quoted.

 ...: optional arguments to ‘FUN’.
```

There-in lies your answer.  In your case, `FUN` is `[`.  The "optional arguments to `fun`" is "2" in your case since it gets matched to `...` in your call.  So in this case, `sapply` is calling `[` with the values in the list as the first argument, and `2` as the second.  Consider:

```
x <- c("G1", "E001")   # this is the result of `strsplit` on the first value
```

Then:

```
`[`(x, 2)      # equivalent to x[2]
# [1] "E001"
```

This is what `sapply` is doing in your example, except it is applying to every 2 length character vector returned by `strsplit`.

Answer (score 6):

You could use `sub` to get the expected output instead of using `strsplit/sapply`

```
 sub('.*:', '', string)
 #[1] "E001" "E002" "E003"
```

Regarding your code, `strsplit` output is a list and list can be processed with apply family functions `sapply/lapply/vapply/rapply` etc.  In this case, each list element have a length of 2 and we are selecting the second element.

```
strsplit(string, ":")
#[[1]]
#[1] "G1"   "E001"

#[[2]]
#[1] "G2"   "E002"

#[[3]]
#[1] "G3"   "E003"

lapply(strsplit(string, ":"), `[`, 2)
#[[1]]
#[1] "E001"

#[[2]]
#[1] "E002"

#[[3]]
#[1] "E003"
```

In the case of `sapply`, the default option is `simplify=TRUE`

```
 sapply(strsplit(string, ":"), `[`, 2, simplify=FALSE)
#[[1]]
#[1] "E001"

#[[2]]
#[1] "E002"

#[[3]]
#[1] "E003"
```

The `[` can be replaced by anonymous function call

```
sapply(strsplit(string, ":"), function(x) x[2], simplify=FALSE)
#[[1]]
#[1] "E001"

#[[2]]
#[1] "E002"

#[[3]]
#[1] "E003"
```

Comment: It's not only a replacement, it's an equivalent. `x[2]` is the same as `\`[\`(x,2)`

Answer (score 2):

Because the output of `strsplit()` is a list. The "[" addresses the elements of the list, and the 2 indicates that the second item of a member of the list is selected. The `sapply()` function ensures that this is done for each member of the list. Here `[` is the function in `sapply()`, which is applied to the list of `strsplit()`and called with the additional parameter 2.

```
> strsplit(string, ":")
#[[1]]
#[1] "G1"   "E001"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "G2"   "E002"
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "G3"   "E003"
#
> str(strsplit(string, ":"))
#List of 3
# $ : chr [1:2] "G1" "E001"
# $ : chr [1:2] "G2" "E002"
# $ : chr [1:2] "G3" "E003"
```